# Can't add button under div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Chrome extension that inserts a button onto HTML pages. I got it to add the button under one div. Now I'm trying to get it to add it under an image in that div, and it won't work — no errors, the button just doesn't appear. When I do console.log(image_div); it prints out the image object.

Version that works:

```
var uCW = jNode.closest("[role='article']");
uCW.append(button);
```

Version that doesn't work:

```
var image_div = $(uCW).find('[src^="https://external"]');
image_div.append(button);
```

uCW is the variable name I gave to the parent div, and image_div is the variable name I gave to the child within uCW that contains the image.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens instead? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: The button just doesn't appear on the page. When I do console.log(image_div); it prints out the image object.

Comment: prints out an image? Now are you appending a button into an image? Also unclear how one is using closest and other is using find

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are having is you are appending to a `div` successfully, but appending to an image is failing. The reason is you can't `append` to an image, you have to use 'after' since an image isn't an object that can content appended to the innerHTML of it.

**So change this:**

```
var image_div = $(uCW).find('[src^="https://external"]');
image_div.append(button);
```

**to:**

```
var image_div = $(uCW).find('[src^="https://external"]');
image_div.after(button);
```

Comment: Hmmm seems to work under a different image though ... Still not sure what's going on, but I think you're right and there's just something weird about the image I'm using. I'll keep fiddling, thanks!